# How to suppress Selenium logs

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, logging

In my automatic test, chrome creates a lot of logs. I tried many ways, none helped. I currently have this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments(
    "--disable-logging",
    "--log-level=OFF",
    "--silent"
);
System.setProperty(browsers.getConfigInfo(),browsers.getDriverPath());

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

but still see this:

```
10:59:11.456 [Forwarding isElementDisplayed on session b316a03b20f1dc9b067b1f59ad01c1ed to remote] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Cache-Control: no-cache
10:59:11.456 [Forwarding isElementDisplayed on session b316a03b20f1dc9b067b1f59ad01c1ed to remote] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: localhost:18288
10:59:11.456 [Forwarding isElementDisplayed on session b316a03b20f1dc9b067b1f59ad01c1ed to remote] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
10:59:11.456 [Forwarding isElementDisplayed on session b316a03b20f1dc9b067b1f59ad01c1ed to remote] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.5 (java 1.5)
10:59:11.456 [Forwarding isElementDisplayed on session b316a03b20f1dc9b067b1f59ad01c1ed to remote] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

Any ideas ;/

Comment: options.addArgument("--log-level=3") did you try this

Comment: I tried it before without any success.

Answer (score -1):

To supress the *Chrome* and [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) related logs you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserLogs\\ChromeDriver_logs.log");
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging", "true");
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.setCapability(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.get("https://www.seleniumhq.org/");
  driver.quit();
  ```
- Console Output (includes the minimum set of logs):

  ```
  Starting ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.16 (320f6526c1632ad4f205ebce69b99a062ed78647-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#185}) on port 9989
  Only local connections are allowed.
  Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
  Feb 06, 2020 3:45:25 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
  INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
  ```

Comment: I need to check other version of ChromeDriver or Chrome Option because I not allowed to do this: 
options.setCapability(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);